# COMMAND TO DISPLAY SPECIFIC LINES IN A SCRIPT

Tags: linux, shell-scripting

I have a script containing 5 lines in it. what is the command to view only 1st and last line in the script in one single expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` to do this:

```
sed -ne '1p;$p' script.sh
```